# How do I place the value of a variable as a parameter in the function when setting the onclick property?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to set an onclick property for a cell in a dynamically created table.

```
tblCellTbl.onclick = function() { atktableDisplay(this.id); };
```

That part works perfectly. However, in updating it, I now want the function to pass a number based on the row, as well. So, I inserted the loop variable (a for loop, with "j" as the counter) into the function as a second parameter.

```
tblCellTbl.onclick = function() { atktableDisplay(this.id,j); };
```

So, each iteration should put "atktableDisplay(this.id, #);" on the appropriate cell/row, where '#' is the number of the row, from 0 to whatever.

When this runs, it generates exactly what it says there, instead of placing the number in the function as a parameter.

```
atktableDisplay(this.id, j);
```

instead of

```
atktableDisplay(this.id, 0);
```

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong that is very simple, but I can't figure it out.

Edit:
The difficulty I'm encountering is that the line quoted is placing the letter "j" into the function parameters where the html is created, instead of the ***value*** of j. I want the value of j (as it loops through the for loop, creating each row).

Here's the for loop code:

```
for (j=0; j<weaponsActualInformation.attacktables.length; j++) {
//lots of things to make table rows and fill them, including
tblCellTbl.onclick = function() { atktableDisplay(this.id,j); };
}
```

EDIT: If I put '0' or 0 in place of the j, everything works. Except that doesn't achieve what I need of applying a different number for each occurrence.

```
tblCellTbl.onclick = function() { atktableDisplay(this.id,0); };
tblCellTbl.onclick = function() { atktableDisplay(this.id,'0'); };
```

Comment: Please show all the relevant code. In this case the loop and the `atktableDisplay` function as well as the `onclick` assignment.

Comment: @ScottMarcus The function 'atktableDisplay' works just fine. The loop is working fine. Heck, the 'onclick' assignment is working fine - except for getting the letter instead of the value. That is literally all the code relevant. (There's a boatload of code in which this simple bit is embedded.)

Comment: Please understand that we're here to help. Very often code that the OP doesn't think is relevant IS relevant and code that the OP thinks works, isn't working the way they thought. From what  you've posted, the code should work, so clearly there's something else that is causing the problem. That's why we always ask for a [minimal and verifiable code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can first reproduce your issue and then help to solve it. In this case, we need to see the `atktableDisplay` function as well to be able to reproduce.